# How to automatically alter object which is being added to a list?

Tags: c#, list

```
class MyClass                { MyClass parent; }    
class Container    : MyClass { List<MyClass> children; }
class NonContainer : MyClass {}
```

I'd like to be able to make `List<MyClass> children` automatically set `parent` value to current `Container` for each `MyClass` instance that is being added to it automatically. I really wouldn't like to place a separate method that does this everywhere I add `MyClass` to `children` in my code.

Throughout my application, I add items to the list in three ways:

1. `children.Add()`
2. `children.AddRange()`
3. `new List<MyClass>(){ new MyClass(){}, /* ... */, new MyClass(){} }`

Maybe there is some better way to make all first gen children know who their parent object is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the children list private and make the children accessible through public methods and properties

```
class Container : MyClass {
    private readonly List<MyClass> _children = new List<MyClass>();

    public void AddChild(MyClass child)
    {
        child.Parent = this;
        _children.Add(child);
    }

    public void AddChildren(IEnumerable<MyClass> children)
    {
        foreach (MyClass child in children) {
            AddChild(child);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyClass> Children { get { return _children; } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit the `List` like this:

```
public class ChildrenList : List<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass Parent { get; private set; }

    public ChildrenList(MyClass parent) { this.Parent = parent; }

    public override void Add(MyClass item)
    {
        item.Parent = Parent;
        base.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Then use it inside your container:

```
class Container : MyClass { List<MyClass> children = new ChildrenList(parent); }
```

Comment: `List<T>.Add` is not virtual; you can't override it. Better would be to inherit from `Collection<MyClass>` and override `InsertItem`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu while you can't overload it you *can* hide it using `public new void Add(MyClass item)`

Comment: @DiskJunky Yeah, but then any usage of it that has it typed as _anything other than `ChildrenList`_ will skip the custom `Add` implementation.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I know but if you're looking to override functionality in some way, you're almost certainly going to explicitly strongly type it. It's a reasonable compromise.